# How to center the caption of a tikz figure ignoring text nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following simple `tikz` picture. See MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{units} % To specify units when computing
\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.
\usepackage{pst-3d, tikz-3dplot} % To draw in 3D.

% FIGURE ITSELF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$(0,0,1)$} -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$(1,0,0)$} -- (2.5,5) node[anchor=south]{$(0,1,0)$} -- cycle;
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (5,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2.5,5);
\coordinate (d) at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\coordinate (e) at ($(a)!1/3!(d)$);
\coordinate (f) at ($(a)!2/3!(d)$);
\node [right] () at (d) {$L_1=(\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2},0)$};
\node [below right] () at (e) {$L_2=(\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{2}{3})$};
\node [above left] () at (f) {$L=(L_1,L_2;\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2})=(\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3})$};
\filldraw [] (d) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [] (e) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [] (f) circle (1pt);
\draw[densely dotted] (a) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\medbreak
\caption{Simplex}\label{f1.1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As it can be seen in the output below, the caption is centered with respect to the entire figure, but I'd like to get it centered with respect to the triangle, only (i.e., ignoring the text). I have seen similar answers to mine that use `use as bounding box` to achieve what I want, but I haven't been able to use it successfully. How should I proceed to achieve what I want?

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: @Hector -- the essential part of your triangle is the code `\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$(0,0,1)$} -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$(1,0,0)$} -- (2.5,5) node[anchor=south]{$(0,1,0)$} -- cycle;`
  -- simply encase it in a bounding box so that the caption will get centered with reference to this bounding box aka the triangle

Comment: @Rmano yes, it compiles just fine in Overleaf.

Comment: @jsbibra Thank you; I will.

Comment: Yes, my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{units} % To specify units when computing
\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.
\usepackage{pst-3d, tikz-3dplot} % To draw in 3D.

% FIGURE ITSELF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$(0,0,1)$} -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$(1,0,0)$} -- (2.5,5) node[anchor=south]{$(0,1,0)$} -- cycle;
            \useasboundingbox (current bounding box);
            \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (b) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (c) at (2.5,5);
            \coordinate (d) at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
            \coordinate (e) at ($(a)!1/3!(d)$);
            \coordinate (f) at ($(a)!2/3!(d)$);
            \node [right] () at (d) {$L_1=(\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2},0)$};
            \node [below right] () at (e) {$L_2=(\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{2}{3})$};
            \node [above left] () at (f) {$L=(L_1,L_2;\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2})=(\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3})$};
            \filldraw [] (d) circle (1pt);
            \filldraw [] (e) circle (1pt);
            \filldraw [] (f) circle (1pt);
            \draw[densely dotted] (a) -- (d);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \medbreak
        \caption{Simplex}\label{f1.1}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
A
```

Comment: @Hector please see if the answer meets the requirement

Comment: Thank you. I was not understanding the syntax of `use as bounding box` correctly. Such a simple thing!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to add white space at the end to make the widths symmetrical w.r.t the center (2.5,2.5).  Reducing the bounding box has the problem of possible overlaps.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{units} % To specify units when computing
\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.
\usepackage{pst-3d, tikz-3dplot} % To draw in 3D.

\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% FIGURE ITSELF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}% measure width
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$(0,0,1)$} -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{$(1,0,0)$} -- (2.5,5) node[anchor=south]{$(0,1,0)$} -- cycle;
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (5,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2.5,5);
\coordinate (d) at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$);
\coordinate (e) at ($(a)!1/3!(d)$);
\coordinate (f) at ($(a)!2/3!(d)$);
\node [right] () at (d) {$L_1=(\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2},0)$};
\node [below right] () at (e) {$L_2=(\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{1}{6},\nicefrac{2}{3})$};
\node [above left] () at (f) {$L=(L_1,L_2;\nicefrac{1}{2},\nicefrac{1}{2})=(\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3},\nicefrac{1}{3})$};
\filldraw [] (d) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [] (e) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [] (f) circle (1pt);
\draw[densely dotted] (a) -- (d);
\path ($(current bounding box.west)!2!(2.5,2.5)$);% add white space relative to center
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\usebox0
\medbreak
\captionof{figure}{Simplex}\label{f1.1}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```